# How to count the sum of same data in access subform

Tags: sum, duplicates, ms-access-2013

I have two access subform. 
  [First Subform (Pivot1234Subform)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXrII.jpg)

1) First is (Pivot1234 subform). Its take pivot1234 table format. Then,this subform will show the data after user selection on listbox and dropdown text box. below are the code that generate this subform:

[Generate PIvot1234 subform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1eUe.jpg)

2. Second subform (CountDuplicateSubform)
   [CountDuplicateSubform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfS7C.jpg)
   this subform is follow query wizard duplicate data of pivot1234 table.

the purpose of this subform is to count the sum of data that containt same data in column FAMILY and WhichTest from pivot1234_subform after the summary in pivot1234 report is clicked.

example 
 if first row  : family = a , whichtest =b
 then second row : family =a , whichtest = b

it will appear in column third (count) "2"

[example of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RW5m.jpg)

below are the code that i already try in Form_Load event:

```
{Private Sub Form_Load()  
Dim strSQL As String 
strSQL = "SELECT First(Pivot123_subform.Family) AS 
[CountDuplicate_subform.Family], First(Pivot1234_subform.WhichTest) AS 
[CountDuplicate_subform.WhichTest], Count(Pivot1234_subform.Family) AS
[CountDuplicate_subform.Count]" & _
"FROM Pivot1234_subform" & _ 
"GROUP BY Pivot1234_subform.Family, Pivot1234_subform.WhichTest" & _
"HAVING (((Count(Pivot1234_subform.Family))>1) AND
((Count(Pivot1234_subform.WhichTest))>1));"

Forms!CountDuplicate_subform.RecordSource = strSQL  
Forms!CountDuplicate_subform.Form.Requery 
End Sub
```

Comment: For one thing, you miss _spaces_: `"FROM Pivot1234_subform " & _`.

Comment: @Gustav i dont understand. I check my coding back. it just same with the code that you already edit.

Comment: You know, coding is about the big picture and the tiniest detail. Thus, look again (hint: _space_).

Comment: @Gustav you mean that there is suppose no “&_” before the from pivot1234_subform and i should just continue write in the same line ?

Comment: okey @Gustav i got it. there is space before " if i wanted to do seperate line like above. Thanks. I will try it again later.

Comment: i already try but the coding didnt want to read my pivot1234 subform T.T help me. im been doing this for 2 weeks already

Comment: Hard to tell, but try this: `Forms!CountDuplicate_subform.Form.RecordSource = strSQL` and `CountDuplicate_subform` must be the name of the subform _control_.

Comment: its okey but thank you so much @Gustav. I already got another alternative to find the total of group family and whichtest by using the group sort total at the report design view footer. Thank you so much !

Comment: Great! Have a nice weekend.